# VBA - write all permutations of numbers to an array

Tags: excel, vba, permutation

Currently i am manually entering the values into array, sign_array(a, b, c). Where c is the level number. So see my output below, where c = 1 there are only two inputs to the array. When c = 2 (or level 2) there are 4 inputs. Level 3 = 8 inputs, level 4 there are 16 inputs. But writing these all out is getting very tiresome.

I am really struggling with this. I need to write to an array all combinations of 1 or 2, and looking for an output of:

```
1    
2
1, 1    
1, 2    
2, 1
2, 2  
1, 1, 1  
2, 1, 1    
1, 2, 1    
1, 1, 2    
2, 2, 1    
2, 1, 2    
1, 2, 2    
2, 2, 2    
1, 1, 1, 1    
2, 1, 1, 1
etc
```

Please see below how far I got, but have no idea what to do, to distinguish between a 1 or a 2. Any help would be greatly appreciated. At the moment i am manually putting in the combinations myself, but I its getting far to big the more dimensions I have.

I don't mind have a for loop for each level creation.

```
levels_to_use = 4
for i = 1 to levels_to_use  ^ 2
    for j = 1 to levels_to_use 
        ' in here how to chose between 1 or 2
        sign_array(i, j, levels_to_use) = 1
    next
next
```

Comment: How many **"Levels"** do you need to cover? or do you need that to be dynamic?

Comment: Ideally dynamic :-( I can't seem to edit the main post, my output numbers are wrong. level 2 = 1, 1 - 1, 2 - 2, 1 - 2, 2 e.g.

Comment: You could loop 2^x where x is the levels, then use a Decimal to Binary converter and replace 0's to 2's?  Outputs like so 0000=0,0001=1,0010=2...

Comment: Just FYI, what you want is called _permutations_. If you google on it you can find some solutions like [this one](http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/generating_permutations/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some time ago, I did not have anything better to do and I wrote exactly the code you are looking for - https://www.vitoshacademy.com/vba-nested-loops-with-recursion/

Thus, if you change it a bit, avoiding the `_` and putting the `size` variable into a loop, it prints the desired result:

[image]

If you change `c = Array(1, 2)` to `c = Array(1, 2, 3)` it would add a third element to the system.

```
Sub Main()

    Static size         As Long
    Static c            As Variant
    Static arr          As Variant
    Static n            As Long

    c = Array(1, 2)
    n = UBound(c) + 1
    For size = 1 To 4
        ReDim arr(size - 1)
        EmbeddedLoops 0, size, c, n, arr
        Debug.Print "---------"
    Next size

End Sub

Function EmbeddedLoops(index, k, c, n, arr)

    Dim i                   As Variant
    If index >= k Then
        PrintArrayInOneLine arr
    Else
        For Each i In c
            arr(index) = i
            EmbeddedLoops index + 1, k, c, n, arr
        Next i
    End If

End Function

Public Sub PrintArrayInOneLine(myArray As Variant)

    Dim counter     As Long
    Dim sArray      As String
    For counter = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
        sArray = sArray & myArray(counter)
    Next counter
    Debug.Print sArray

End Sub
```

Comment: You genius! So i could use the sArray and loop over each character in the string?

Comment: @Surreall - Welcome. Concerning the `sArray` and looping over its characters - it is better to avoid writing to a string, but simply looping through `myArray`.

Comment: Worked a treat, thank you! This was driving me crazy.